# Ubuntu will not accept new password even after recovery mode reset

Tags: updates, login-screen

After a recent 14.04 update my computer will not accept my log in password. I have done all the various steps through the recovery mode at boot up, changed my admin password & I still receive an invalid password message. I've also noticed while rebooting there is a "FAIL" alert in red next to active drive server.

This all began with an update, the continuous crashing of Firefox then the inability to log in after a restart. Please help

Comment: Can you log in through the terminal? To do that, press Ctrl+Alt+F1 when presented with the graphical login (or at any point after normal start-up). Press Ctrl+Alt+F7 to return to graphical mode.

Comment: Tried this without success. Im wondering if I need to reinstall ubuntu or somwthing although it looks as if my settings are intact. My home screen still show my settings in the background tho.

Comment: Also, it wont allow a guest log in either.

Comment: Ok, that restricts the source of the problem. Can you please post the content of `/var/log/auth.log`? Start Ubuntu in [single user](/q/132965/175814) or [recovery mode](//wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) and [copy or upload](/q/440087/175814) the file. Alternatively boot from DVD/USB, select the option “Try Ubuntu”, open your on-disk Linux partition and copy or upload the file.

Comment: Where is the " /var/log/auth.log" found? Do not have the DVD/USB

Comment: If you can't login from a normal boot up, then boot from a live CD. Once that's running do something like sudo mkdir /media/work; sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/work; cd /media/work; sudo cat var/log/auth.log  --- do the commands one at a time. I can't format them nicely in a comment. That will let you see the log contents. Then the trick is getting them into a post here. If your live cd will let you get on the web with a browser, then you can just copy and paste the log into a post here. If not, save it to a flash drive and post from that on a computer that does work.

Comment: Continued: I don't do live cds very often, so I'm not sure what a live cd calls its root partition. It's probably not /dev/sda1 - which should be your computer's boot drive's first partition where the log lives. If you installed Linux on another partition, substitute its device name for /dev/sda1.